# App is crashing on initWithStyle

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I can't get why my app crashes. Here is the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blue", @"Yellow", @"Green", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [self.tableContent count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    return [self.tableContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Here is the error I got

```
-[NSCFString setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4938
```

Comment: Somewhere, you are sending a setTableViewStyle message to an NSString object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the error in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
return [self.tableContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`tableContent` is an array of `NSString`s, so you're returning an `NSString` instead of an object of type `UITableViewCell`. So instead write:

```
return cell;
```

It is the `NSString` you've returned in place of the `UITableViewCell` that causes the error...If you want to see the text you're sending, you'll need to set the textlabel's text:

```
cell.textlabel.text = [self.tableContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//set the text and then return the cell
return cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not allocating self.tableContent, that can make you have a memory acces error. If you are going to use self.tableContent all along your class, you should do:

```
self.tableContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Blue", @"Yellow", @"Green", nil];
```

On the other hand, you are returning a NSString instead of a cell here:

```
return [self.tableContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You should do:

```
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use at last

```
[return cell];
```